# Asset pipelining stylesheets and JavaScript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have lots of stylesheets in my rails app. Many stylesheets are using some more plugins like

```
require plugins/jquery.ptTimeSelect
```

etc.

Can these extra plugins be called using

```
*= require....
```

in the main `application.css` or should they be used in the specific stylesheets where they are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in application.css as at the end after assets are precompiled. All the stylesheets will be concatenated to form single application.css file.